# How to fix "Microsoft Office Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space"?

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel, excel-interop

I am trying to export a dataset in my website to excel. 
The code is working fine on local machine but when I am deploying the same to win. server im getting following error :

[image]

I am using following code :

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("New_DataSet");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("New_DataTable");

    string constr = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionInfo"];
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    SqlDataAdapter adptr = new SqlDataAdapter();

    adptr.SelectCommand = cmd;
    adptr.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();

    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    MyExcel.Application oXL;
    MyExcel.Workbook oWB;
    MyExcel.Worksheet oSheet;
    MyExcel.Range oRange;
```

//        Worksheets sheets = excelApp.Worksheets; // <-- the important part
//Worksheet sheet = sheets.Open(...);

```
    oXL = new MyExcel.Application();

    oXL.Visible = true;
    oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
    oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(System.Type.Missing);
    //oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(System.Type.Missing);

    oSheet = (MyExcel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
    oSheet.Name = "Customers";

    int rowCount = 1;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        rowCount += 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            // Add the header the first time through 
            if (rowCount == 2)
            {
                oSheet.Cells[1, i] = dt.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
            }
            oSheet.Cells[rowCount, i] = dr[i - 1].ToString();
        }
    }

    // Resize the columns 
    oRange = oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[1, 1],
                  oSheet.Cells[rowCount, dt.Columns.Count]);
    oRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

    // Save the sheet and close 


    oWB.SaveAs("test.xlsx", MyExcel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing,
        MyExcel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);

    oSheet = null;
    oRange = null;
    oWB = null;
    oXL = null;

     oWB.Close(false, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oWB);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oXL);

    oXL.Quit();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSheet);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSheet);


    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
```

I am not getting any fix for this. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Just for be sure. You've checked there's enough disk space where you're trying to save data?

Comment: yes obviously .. lots of GBs is free

Comment: @c0D3l0g1c've given the answer. Just to suggest, you should always put Close/Quit/... in a "finally" block

Answer (score 2):

If you have checked that you have enough free space available then the only other issue it could be is permissions.

Hope you find this link useful:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/87128/Unable-to-write-data-runtime-in-Excel-app-using-c